# Task.async_stream timeout behaviour

Tags: elixir

In the [Task.async_stream options](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#async_stream/5-options), the `:timeout` parameter is described:

> The maximum amount of time (in milliseconds) each task is allowed to execute for. Defaults to 5000

In my testing I did the following:

```
iex(8)> Task.async_stream([10, 4, 5], fn i -> :timer.sleep(i * 1000); i end) |> Enum.to_list
[ok: 10, ok: 4, ok: 5]

iex(10)> Task.async_stream([10], fn i -> :timer.sleep(i * 1000); i end) |> Enum.to_list      
** (exit) exited in: Task.Supervised.stream(5000)
    ** (EXIT) time out
    (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:209: Task.Supervised.stream_reduce/10
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1776: Enum.reverse/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:2528: Enum.to_list/1
```

How come the first example does not timeout (but takes ~10 seconds to execute) while the second example exhibits the expected behaviour of timing out?

Comment: I'm getting a timeout for both the code snippets.

Comment: Same here - times out for me. Which version of Elixir do you use?

Comment: Im using version 1.4.5

Comment: I don't have an install of 1.4.5 to test but on 1.5.1 this definitely consistently times out as expected.

Answer (score 6):

The implementation of `Task.async_stream` changed from 1.4.5 to 1.5.1.

Let's take a look at what happens.

### Elixir 1.4.5

In this version the [timeout is part of a `receive`s `after` block](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/e25c37108a5294b205ad0abe558cb82f19d342c5/lib/elixir/lib/task/supervised.ex#L206-L210).

```
receive do
  {{^monitor_ref, position}, value} ->
    # ...

  {:down, {^monitor_ref, position}, reason} ->
    # ...

  {:DOWN, ^monitor_ref, _, ^monitor_pid, reason} ->
    # ...
after
  timeout ->
    # ...
end
```

This `receive` block serves the purpose to wait for update messages from the spawned tasks sent from a monitoring process. For simplicity reasons I truncated the code.

What does that mean in an applied scenario? `Task.async_stream` will only timeout if there is a duration of `timeout` milliseconds in which it receives no message from a spawned task.

#### Example

Lets try your example using `[10, 3, 4]`:

```
iex> Task.async_stream([10, 3, 4], fn i -> :timer.sleep(i * 1000); i end) |> Enum.to_list
** (exit) exited in: Task.Supervised.stream(5000)
    ** (EXIT) time out
    (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:209: Task.Supervised.stream_reduce/10
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1776: Enum.reverse/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:2528: Enum.to_list/1
```

As we can see this results in a timeout, as expected.

Now what if we try to use `[10, 5]`, will this work?

```
iex> Task.async_stream([10, 5], fn i -> :timer.sleep(i * 1000); i end) |> Enum.to_list()
** (exit) exited in: Task.Supervised.stream(5000)
    ** (EXIT) time out
    (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:209: Task.Supervised.stream_reduce/10
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1776: Enum.reverse/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:2528: Enum.to_list/1
```

As it seems the initial Task takes too long with it's 5 seconds timeout. But as soon as we add an intermediary step, it works. How about `1`?

```
iex> Task.async_stream([10, 5, 1], fn i -> :timer.sleep(i * 1000); i end) |> Enum.to_list()
[ok: 10, ok: 5, ok: 1]
```

### Elixir 1.5.1

In Elixir 1.5.1 the timeout logic works differently. It uses `Process.send_after` to send a timeout message for each spawned Task to the monitoring process.

```
# Schedule a timeout message to ourselves, unless the timeout was set to :infinity
timer_ref = case timeout do
  :infinity -> nil
  timeout -> Process.send_after(self(), {:timeout, {monitor_ref, ref}}, timeout)
end
```

This message is then [handled in the same receive which spawned the Task and sent the `:timeout` message](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/1406d853e0e6515007696f871d0a9e2c023da6da/lib/elixir/lib/task/supervised.ex#L459-L472).

[Link to the full function.](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.5.1/lib/elixir/lib/task/supervised.ex#L398)

#### Examples

As soon as a single process takes longer than the specified timeout, the whole stream goes to it's knees, as it should be.

```
iex> Task.async_stream([10, 5, 1], fn i -> :timer.sleep(i * 1000); i end) |> Enum.to_list()
** (exit) exited in: Task.Supervised.stream(5000)
    ** (EXIT) time out
    (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:237: Task.Supervised.stream_reduce/7
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1847: Enum.reverse/1
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:2596: Enum.to_list/1
```

### TL;DR

Elixir 1.4.5 tracks the timeout anew after receiving a result from a spawned process. Elixir 1.5.1 tracks it separately for each spawned process.